# Reading a Textfile that has names and grades to an array list to later use for average

Tags: java, arraylist, input, text-files

I have a textfile that looks something like this:

**John Smith   94 88 77 99

Peter Griffin 88 34 55 78**

What I am trying to do is read each word using next() and then store that into an array list. From here. I need to identity the individual names and their respective marks. I don't know if I should be using next line so that each person is on a seperate line but what confuses me is using a for loop so that I do not need to manually hard code this. If I have 20 students each with 4 marks and a name and a last name should i store them all in arrays? I can't seem to figure out the loop restrictions. Also im trying to understand the basics behind this so nothing too complex.

```
  public static ArrayList<String> readFile(String file)throws IOException{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("grades.txt"));
    ArrayList<Integer> allMarks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    while(reader.hasNext()){
        String line = reader.next();//first and last names
        list.add(line);
        }
    //System.out.println(list);
    
    //first students name and grades
   
    //hard coding element here represents one student's info
   String fName = list.get(8);
   String lName = list.get(9);
   String mark1 = list.get(10);
   String mark2 = list.get(11);
   String mark3 = list.get(12);
   String mark4 = list.get(13);
   
   
   
   
   
   int sum = Integer.parseInt(mark1)+Integer.parseInt(mark2)+Integer.parseInt(mark3)+Integer.parseInt(mark4);
   double average = sum/4;
   System.out.println(fName+lName +" "+ average);
    
      

    return(list);
}
```

}

Comment: Use `hasNextLine` and `nextLine` to read each line of the file, you can then use a seperate `Scanner` to parse the line of text, or just `String#split`. I'd also make use of a POJO (plain old java object) to store the information for each student, but that's me

Comment: What you want to return in the function?

Answer (score 0):

> What I am trying to do is read each word using next() and then store that into an array list

First, create a `Student` object of some kind, which can hold the basic information you're loading, for example...

```
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Integer> grades;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, List<Integer> grades) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.grades = grades;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGrades() {
        return grades;
    }
}
```

Then, use `Scanner#hasNextLine` and `Scanner#nextLine` to read the entire line of text from the file.  You could use `String#split`, but then you'd have to manually convert the `String` grades to `int`.  In this case, you can use another `Scanner` to simply parse the line of text, for example...

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("grades.txt"));
while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    Scanner parser = new Scanner(line);
    String firstName = parser.next();
    String lastName = parser.next();
    List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<>(4);
    while (parser.hasNextInt()) {
        grades.add(parser.nextInt());
    }
    Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, grades);
}
```

This should be wrapped up into a method which stores each student in a list of some kind, for example...

```
public List<Student> loadStudents() throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(16);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("grades.txt"));
    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = reader.nextLine();
        Scanner parser = new Scanner(line);
        String firstName = parser.next();
        String lastName = parser.next();
        List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<>(4);
        while (parser.hasNextInt()) {
            grades.add(parser.nextInt());
        }
        Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, grades);
        students.add(student);
    }
    return students;
}
```

> I need to identity the individual names and their respective marks

Okay, this is seperate work flow, so you would load the student details, then use a seperate loop to loop over the `List` and generate the output.

Since this is some repeating functionality, we could simply add some helper methods to the `Student` class to do it for us!

```
public class Student {
    //...
    public String getName() {
        return (getFirstName() + " " + getLastName()).trim();
    }

    public int sumGrades() {
        int total = 0;
        for (int grade : getGrades()) {
            total += grade;
        }
        return total;
    }

    public double gradeAverage() {
        return sumGrades() / (double) getGrades().size();
    }
}
```

Now, we just just loop over the `List` of students and print the averages, for example...

```
for (Student student : loadStudents()) {
    System.out.println(student.getName() + " grade average " + student.gradeAverage());
}
```

Now, this is not the only way you could do this, but when ever you're dealing with structured data, it's a good idea to try and encapsulate it into some kind of class, it's easier then dealing with array indices

## Runnable example...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() throws FileNotFoundException {
        for (Student student : loadStudents()) {
            System.out.println(student.getName() + " grade average " + student.gradeAverage());
        }
    }

    public List<Student> loadStudents() throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(16);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("grades.txt"));
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = reader.nextLine();
            Scanner parser = new Scanner(line);
            String firstName = parser.next();
            String lastName = parser.next();
            List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<>(4);
            while (parser.hasNextInt()) {
                grades.add(parser.nextInt());
            }
            Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, grades);
            students.add(student);
        }
        return students;
    }

    public class Student {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private List<Integer> grades;

        public Student(String firstName, String lastName, List<Integer> grades) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.grades = grades;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public List<Integer> getGrades() {
            return grades;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return (getFirstName() + " " + getLastName()).trim();
        }

        public int sumGrades() {
            int total = 0;
            for (int grade : getGrades()) {
                total += grade;
            }
            return total;
        }

        public double gradeAverage() {
            return sumGrades() / (double) getGrades().size();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when I add my friend jean paul van der graaf?

Comment: @mgh42 Then, we go back to the architecture and beat them with a brick for not using a more appropriate file format - the brief was, first and last name, so, trying to keep it simple, I stuck with it. Of course you could use `while (parser.hasNext() && !parser.hasNextInt()) {...}` or something as such

Comment: fair enough to stick to the brief, i just like an excuse to bring up this nice list of assumptions people make about names https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/